# SQLAlchemy update multiple rows in one transaction

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sql-update

How can I update multiple, existing rows in a database, using dictionary that maps existing values for one column, to the required new values for another column?

I have a table:

```
class MyTable(BaseModel):
    col1 = sa.Column(sa.String(256))
    col2 = sa.Column(sa.String(256))
```

Given that `col1` has already values and `col2` is empty, how can I update `col2` if I have the set of data as a dictionary:

```
payload = {'x': 'y', 'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
```

So this payload maps values for `col1`, to a *new* value for `col2`; after the update you'd get `[{'col1': 'x', 'col2': 'y'}, ...]` from the database.

I tried a couple of ways, which actually work but I think they are not as optimal as it could be ex.:

```
my_table = MyTable.__table__
for key, value in payload.items():
    stm = my_table.update()
    stm = stm.where(getattr(sales_order_item.c, 'col1') == key)
    stm = stm.values({'col2': value})
    session.execute(stm)
```

Or like this

```
for key, value in payload.items():
    query = session.query(MyTable).filter(MyTable.col1==key)
    query.update({MyTable.col2: value})
```

Now both of these solutions work as expected the only thing that is bothering me is the time it takes, for example for a payload of 100 elements it takes up to 6 sec, and I'm almost sure that there should be a better way to do that, isn't it?

I was thinking if there is a way of making it work with the `in_` function:

```
query(MyTable).filter(
        MyTable.col1.in_(payload.keys())
    )
```

but I don't know how to structure the update query.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, updating a larger number of rows with a single bulk `UPDATE` statement will be a lot faster than using individual `UPDATE`s on each and every object. An `IN` filter would only help you limit what rows are updated, but you still need to tell the database what value to use for the `col2` updates.

You can use a `CASE ... WHEN ... THEN` construct for that, with the [`case()` function](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.case):

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import case

query(MyTable).filter(
    MyTable.col1.in_(payload)
).update({
    MyTable.col2: case(
        payload,
        value=MyTable.col1,
    )
}, synchronize_session=False)
```

The above a) selects rows where the `col1` value is a key in the `payload` dictionary, then b) updates the `col2` column value using a `CASE` statement that picks values from that same dictionary to update that column based on matching `col1` against the keys.

With `payload` set to `{'x': 'y', 'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}`, the above executes the following query (give or take the exact order of `WHEN` clauses and values in the `IN` test):

```sql
UPDATE mytable
SET
    col2=CASE mytable.col1
        WHEN 'x' THEN 'y'
        WHEN 'a' THEN 'b'
        WHEN 'c' THEN 'd'
    END
WHERE
    mytable.col1 IN ('x', 'a', 'c')
```

I set `synchronize_session` to `False` there, as updating all possible cached `MyTable` instances at once is perhaps not the best idea when updating a large number of rows. Your other options are `'evaluate'` and `'fetch'`.

- We can't use the default `'evaluate'` (which would find existing objects in the session that match the `where` clause, to update in-place), because SQLAlchemy currently doesn't know how to process an `IN` filter (you get an `UnevaluatableError` exception).
- If you do use `'fetch'` then all instances of `MyTable` cached in the session that were affected are updated with new values for `col2` (as mapped by their primary key).

Note that a commit would expire the session *anyway*, so you'd only want to use `'fetch'` if you need to do some more work with the updated rows before you can commit the current transaction.

See the [`Query.update()` documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.update) for more information on what `synchronize_session` options you have.

Comment: This turned out to be a RAM killer and took more time compared to  `bulk_update_mappings` or custom query in my case (80000 keys payload)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution that I found before the chosen answer which also works fast would be:

```
# payload = {'x': 'y', 'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
all_rows = query(MyTable).filter(
    MyTable.col1.in_(payload)
)
for row in all_rows:
    row.col2=payload[row.col1]
```

This would do a`SELECT` though, which will add a couple of seconds, but is helpful to someone who finds it more convenient having the full row, also giving more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

As an extension to @Martijn's excellent answer i've done it in a way that allows you to increment rather than set the value:

```
# List of items to increment [id, increment value]
increments = [
    [1,1],
    [2,5],
    [3,8]
]
# Extract ids
ids = [v[0] for v in increments]
# Create payload
payload = {
    v[0]:Table.col2 + v[1] for v in increments
}
# Get the product
query(Table) \
    .filter(Products.col1.in_(ids)) \
    .update({
        Table.col2: case(
            payload, 
            value=Table.col1
        )
    })
```