# Update multiple rows in ORM model at once

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I got orm object like this:

```
class Fruit(ModelBase):
    __tablename__ = "fruits"
    id = Column(BigInteger, nullable=False)
    name = Column(Unicode)
    price = Column(Integer)
```

and my table looks like this:

```
+----+--------+-------+
| id |  name  | price |
+----+--------+-------+
|  1 | apple  |   100 |
|  2 | carrot |   200 |
|  3 | orange |   300 |
+----+--------+-------+
```

I want to update my orm object with data so my table would look like this:

```
+----+--------+-------+
| id |  name  | price |
+----+--------+-------+
|  1 | apple  |   500 |
|  2 | carrot |   200 |
|  3 | orange |   600 |
+----+--------+-------+
```

Fruits

```
updated_data = [{"id": 1, "name": "apple", "price": 500}, {"id": 3, "name": "orange", "price": 600}]
```

How can I update my orm object **Fruits** having data from updated_data list?

I tried with

```
update(Fruit).where(Fruit.id == updated_data.id).values(updated_data)
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [`executemany`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0249/#executemany) approach, as stated in the [SQLAlchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/data_update.html#the-update-sql-expression-construct):

> *To support UPDATE in an “executemany” context, where many parameter sets will be invoked against the same statement, the bindparam() construct may be used to set up bound parameters; these replace the places that literal values would normally go:*

I.e., for your specific case, this could be:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import bindparam

query = (
    update(Fruit)
    .where(Fruit.id == bindparam("fruit_id"))
    .values(
        name=bindparam("fruit_name"),
        price=bindparam("fruit_price"),
    )
)

with Session(engine) as session:
    cursor_result = session.execute(
        statement=query,
        params=[
            {
                "fruit_id": 1, 
                "fruit_name": "apple", 
                "fruit_price": 500
            },
            {
                "fruit_id": 3, 
                "fruit_name": "orange", 
                "fruit_price": 600
            },
        ],
    )
```

**Warnings:**

- The `cursor_result` will not have access to the updated rows. If you need to return the updated ORM objects, you will need to do a subsequent `SELECT` to fetch them. The reason for this is explained by the SQLAlchemy library author in [this GitHub discussion with another developer](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/7980#discussioncomment-2671042).
- You **really need** to name the dictionary items in the `params` argument in a different way than the `Fruit` ORM object attributes (columns), as the internals of this mapping functionality requires to be like that. Otherwise you will get an exception, like e.g.

  ```
  sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: bindparam() name 'price' is reserved for
    automatic usage in the VALUES or SET clause of this insert/update
    statement. Please use a name other than column name when using
    bindparam() with insert() or update() (for example, 'b_price')
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code would work if you were to do one row at a time instead of passing the whole list to values(). Something like this should do it:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

with Session(engine) as session:
    for fruit in updated_data:
        session.execute(
            update(Fruit).
            where(Fruit.id == fruit["id"]).
            values(fruit)
        )
    session.commit()
```

If running one query for each row turns out to be slow, you could check out this answer here: [SQLAlchemy update multiple rows in one transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54365873/sqlalchemy-update-multiple-rows-in-one-transaction)